# Playing Audio Files on Asp.Net in Sequence(one after one)

Tags: asp.net, javascript, multimedia

I have a reqiurement, I need to play multiple audio songson ASP.Net page.Can anyone suggest the best way to implement this.

I have page. There I will display the list of the songs in grid view. The gridview contains checkboxes and songs name. User should able to select the  multiple check boxes and click play.

When ever user click play button on new popup window I have to play the all audio songs selected by user one by one.

I will appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Venkat.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to use [jPlayer](http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/) - jQuery audio player plugin.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET is server-side. To play a sound on the visitor's computer, you need to use something that runs client-side. JavaScript, Flash, Java, etc. If you play a sound in your ASP.NET code, it will play on the server. Not remotely useful... Get it? "Remotely?" Haha!

Answer (score 0):

What format is the audio in?

The best way would be to dynamically create a playlist file (.asx|.m3u) and serve it to the browser/media player.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mediaEnded` Event of mediaplayer(silverlight) in javascript